# Pass values from parent to child LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am trying to pass value from parent LWC component to child LWC component, but i am getting "undefined" error. Am i doing anything wrong.

Parent :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <lightning-input type="text" value={checknameinputvalue} name="CheckName" label="Check Name" required></lightning-input>
    <lightning-button label="Generate" title="Generate" class="slds-m-left_x-small" onclick={handleClick} ></lightning-button>
    <c-cHildTestLWC check-name={checknameinputvalue}></c-cHildTestLWC>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";

export default class TestcheckDetails extends LightningElement {
  @track checknameinputvalue;

  handleClick(event) {
    this.checknameinputvalue = event.target.value;
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post the child component code.

Comment: child component is 1000 line of code.. i cant paste it...The error which i am getting is console.log(event.target.value); is showing undefined..

Comment: you have to ckeck if it is not undefined (in other way you add a condition in order to send a not empty value
<template if:true={checknameinputvalue}>
<c-cHildTestLWC check-name={checknameinputvalue}></c-cHildTestLWC>
</template>

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that you're trying to set the value from the click event on the button. The property `event.target` is the button itself because the event is raised by the button.

You have to add an event to the `lightning-input` when the input is changed. Then, you'll be able to get the current value.

The right code for your component is:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <lightning-input type="text" value={checknameinputvalue} name="CheckName" label="Check Name" required onchange={handleInputChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-button label="Generate" title="Generate" class="slds-m-left_x-small" onclick={handleClick} ></lightning-button>
    <c-cHildTestLWC check-name={checkNameValue}></c-cHildTestLWC>
  </div>
</template>
```

And for your controller:

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";

export default class TestcheckDetails extends LightningElement {
  @track checknameinputvalue;
  checkNameValue;

  handleInputChange(event) {
    this.checknameinputvalue = event.target.value;
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
  handleClick(event){
    this.checkNameValue = this.checknameinputvalue;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want the value to be only changed when the button is clicked, then you should add a second variable. The new variable will be send to your child component and will only be updated when the button is clicked thanks to a click event added to the button.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for the code. but thts not what i want.. I want i will type something in the input text box and on the button click i want to assign tht value in the child component.So on button click i need tht value..

Comment: @learningmode I updated my code.